# SMTP server configuration changes for Ubuntu 9.10 (Karmic Koala)

Tags: ubuntu, smtp

I will start to say that I am  **cough** a MS dev and not a sys admin so please go easy.

I have a server on the cloud that runs `Ubuntu 9.10 (Karmic Koala)` and is just a mail server. A lost friend of mine set this up for me, all works fine and it has been running for a couple of years.

The server currently has a single mail user setup and has IP filtering turned on.

However I need to make a couple of mods:-

1. Add new mail users so I can hand out usernames and passwords to a couple of clients
2. Add new IP addresses to the safe sender list (or whatever you call it)

However I got no idea where to start and could do with a few pointers (tutorials) showing me how I do these two basic tasks.

Can anyone help?

```
root@smtpauth:/# ps -ef | egrep -i "mail|post|exim"
root      2404     1  0 Apr09 ?        00:00:02 /usr/lib/postfix/master
postfix   2412  2404  0 Apr09 ?        00:00:00 qmgr -l -t fifo -u
root      2413     1  0 Apr09 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/dovecot -c /etc/dovecot/dovecot-postfix.conf
postfix   2471  2404  0 Apr09 ?        00:00:00 tlsmgr -l -t unix -u -c
postfix  32299  2404  0 13:44 ?        00:00:00 pickup -l -t fifo -u -c
```

**edit2**
I have found this as an old note

ADD USER

```
cd /
useradd smtpuser 
passwd smtpuser 
KEY IN PWD
```

then

```
cd /etc/postfix
ls -l
cp main.cf main.cf~working20120504
nano main.cf
CTRL + w type in mynetworks
OR user up down arrows to find mynetworks
add space then IP address
CTRL + x
then press Y
/etc/init.d/postfix reload
```

So it looks like I first add a user then add IP address to a config setting called mynetworks.

Comment: Very sorry to hear about your friend. What sort of mail server is it?

Comment: @Sirch thanks, How do I find that out? Think of me as a linux novice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can tell me what mail server you are running, I'll be happy to help. If its running, which I'm sure it is, youll see it under

```
ps -ef
```

Look for 'mail' 'postfix' 'exim' 'sendmail'

```
ps -ef | egrep -i "mail|post|exim"
```

If its postfix, heres a link to ubuntu's howto.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixBasicSetupHowto

Adding new addresses to the safe sender list, or whatever you mean, will be carried out by the server, your mailboxes will be services by dovecot.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dovecot

So now i wonder where the user mail is kept, are your mail users maintained in the operating system? Do you see them in /etc/passwd and are the directories mentioned look like they may be for customers?

Comment: Have added output from `ps -ef | egrep -i "mail|post|exim"`

Comment: Hi Sirch, I have managed to find a very old note from an old backup. Thanks for you input you helped me by mentioning the word postfix that I was able to search for. I will accept your answer.